# how to make wordpress remember my choice

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, redirect, plugin-recommendation

i have a wordpress network site for multi language purpose
now for example i have
example.com -- > the main site
example.com/en --> English site

### example.com/fr --> french site

i want to add in the main site example.com two buttons one for English and the another for french but i want wordpress the main site remember my choice so when i go to the main site next time i don't have to choose the language again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a cookie. If it's the visitor's first time, set a cookie. Let the user set the cookie once he clicks on the language he wants.

You may refer to his sample [Wordpress Redirect based on the prescence of a cookie](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24885/wordpress-redirect-based-on-the-prescence-of-a-cookie)

You may tweak it a bit to do something like

```
 if ( !isset($_COOKIE["language"])) {
        if(!isset($_GET["language"])){ // Check if user has set a language through a get function
           setcookie('language', 1, time()+1209600, "/", "http://www,yourdomain.com/".$_GET['language']."", false); // Set the chosen cookie
           wp_redirect( get_site_url().'/'.$_GET['language'] ); exit; // redirect to the chosen language
        }else{
          setcookie('language', 1, time()+1209600, "/", "http://www,yourdomain.com/en", false); // If did not choose, just redirect to your default language
        }
    }else{
        wp_redirect( get_site_url().'/'.$_COOKIE['language'] ); exit; // Else, redirect to the language based on the cookie stored previously
    }
```

Comment: thank you for helping me
i'm not adeveloper
may ypu told me in details how to use this
and my page for example have this html code
<a href="site1url">site1url</a>
<a href="site2url">site2url</a>

--
and can i use javascript for this ?

Comment: You can do something like <a href="http://www.yourdomain,com/?language="en">English Flag Here</a>